# Runtime.nativeLoad crashes when loading private library

Tags: android, linker, dalvik, native-code

```
SIGSEGV: SIGSEGV
#00 pc 4009a4c0 /system/bin/linker
#01 pc 4009b004 /system/bin/linker
#02 pc 4009b416 /system/bin/linker
#03 pc 4009b9ca /system/bin/linker
#04 pc 40099f42 /system/bin/linker
#05 pc 00051074 /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z17dvmLoadNativeCodePKcP6ObjectPPc)
#06 pc 00068a18 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#07 pc 00027fa0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#08 pc 0002f110 /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z11dvmMterpStdP6Thread)
#09 pc 0002c774 /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z12dvmInterpretP6ThreadPK6MethodP6JValue)
#10 pc 000619ea /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z15dvmInvokeMethodP6ObjectPK6MethodP11ArrayObjectS5_P11ClassObjectb)
#11 pc 00069af6 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#12 pc 00027fa0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#13 pc 0002f110 /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z11dvmMterpStdP6Thread)
#14 pc 0002c774 /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z12dvmInterpretP6ThreadPK6MethodP6JValue)
#15 pc 000619ea /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z15dvmInvokeMethodP6ObjectPK6MethodP11ArrayObjectS5_P11ClassObjectb)
#16 pc 00069af6 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#17 pc 00027fa0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#18 pc 0002f110 /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z11dvmMterpStdP6Thread)
#19 pc 0002c774 /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z12dvmInterpretP6ThreadPK6MethodP6JValue)
#20 pc 000619ea /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z15dvmInvokeMethodP6ObjectPK6MethodP11ArrayObjectS5_P11ClassObjectb)
#21 pc 00069af6 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#22 pc 00027fa0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#23 pc 0002f110 /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z11dvmMterpStdP6Thread)
#24 pc 0002c774 /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z12dvmInterpretP6ThreadPK6MethodP6JValue)
#25 pc 00061706 /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z14dvmCallMethodVP6ThreadPK6MethodP6ObjectbP6JValueSt9__va_list)
#26 pc 0004ae1a /system/lib/libdvm.so
#27 pc 00050546 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#28 pc 000512d2 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime5startEPKcS2_)
#29 pc 4009605c /system/bin/app_process
#30 pc 0000e5e6 /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init)
java:
java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
java.lang.Runtime.doLoad(Runtime.java:421)
java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:331)
java.lang.System.load(System.java:541)
....
```

It crashes at this line when trying to load a private library(.so):

```
System.load(so_path);
```

In addition, this code is invoked from a customized **DexClassLoader**, which loads a lot of private classes in associated with the native code in **".so"**.

However on most devices it is loaded regularly. And this issue is mostly found on devices with android api level 17, 16, 19.

Does any one have any experience or any idea about this issue? Thank you very much!

Comment: Is this something you can reproduce, or is it just coming from older devices in the field?

Comment: It is reported from our product users, and my device can not reproduce it.